# Get transactions by block for BSC

Tags: bsc, bscscan

is there an API where I can query all transactions for a specific block for BSC? Alternatively, is there any other way to do it without running a node? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes there are APIs you can use to achieve that. For example you could use Moralis to get all information about a specific block.
Lets take the block with this hash as an example:
`0xc659c5a1399c2c3b753a2cb812b4004359a7edc1913545f6741cd444d53498a7`
https://bscscan.com/block/22684589

This request returns all about this block, by using the block hash - in the response you can find an array called `transactions`. You need your API key from moralis.io to execute this request.
Note the `chain` parameter in the URL which is set to `bsc` in this case.

```
curl --request GET \
     --url 'https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/block/0xc659c5a1399c2c3b753a2cb812b4004359a7edc1913545f6741cd444d53498a7?chain=bsc' \
     --header 'X-API-Key: YOU_MORALIS_API_KEY' \
     --header 'accept: application/json'
```

Link to Moralis docs: https://docs.moralis.io/reference/getblock

```
  [1]: https://bscscan.com/block/22684589
  [2]: https://moralis.io
```